# Flask Javascript Array display in html?

Tags: javascript, flask

I have an array being rendered into my Flask route. I have it showing up via this code:

```
      <script>
        var purchases = JSON.parse('{{ purchase | safe }}');
        console.log(purchases)
     </script>
```

Trying to loop through purchases, though, in the DOM with the code below and getting nothing.

```
            {% for p in purchases %}
                {{ p.MLSNumber }}
            {% endfor %}
```

The array is there, just can't seem to access it (here is an example of the console)

```
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {BedsTotal: '2', ListPrice: 99500, MLSAreaMinor: 'Williams', MLSNumber: '7058585', PostalCode: '80821', …}
1: {BedsTotal: '1', ListPrice: 58000, MLSAreaMinor: 'Ramah', MLSNumber: '9555642', PostalCode: '64620', …}
2: {BedsTotal: '1', ListPrice: 90000, MLSAreaMinor: 'Unknown', MLSNumber: '1936385', PostalCode: '81006', …}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have an array formatted in JSON. If you want to iterate, you should use Javascript. Jinja2 should be used on the server at render time. For example, to go through Python lists and dicts and integrate their content into the HTML code. JavaScript is used for operation in the browser, i.e. the client, and can handle JSON / JavaScript data. What is your intention? Why do you use JSON data and what should be done with the data?

Comment: Good questions. I am trying to wrap my head around how this should flow. But here is what is happening: 

1. I have a request in for a list of homes 
2. I get this object in, convert it to a Pandas DF for filtering 
3. I convert this dataframe to a dictionary 
4. I have a filter function on the dictionary whose results I am trying to display in the page 

When I return just the list (filtered dictionary), I get "the view function did not return a valid response" 

The only method of returning the filtered object I have found seems to be this array formatted in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you, you want to filter a list of homes based on an indication of the maximum price. In this case you can use JSON, but this is not absolutely necessary. Especially if you don't want to load the data within an AJAX request, I would avoid that.

In the following example, form data is transmitted to the server, a dictionary you mentioned is filtered and the results are presented on the page.
In contrast to you, I use a GET request for the sake of simplicity. The values are sent as parameters within the URL. But there is nothing against using a POST request to transport the form data in the request body and to protect it from the eyes of third parties.
With both variants, the input can be converted into a float when the request is made from the request object by specifying the type attribute. It is also possible to specify a default value.
I use a custom jinja2 filter to format the price.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter()
def format_currency(value):
    return "$ {:,.2f}".format(value)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'MLSNumber': [9504716, 4426383],
    'ListPrice': [659849.00, 1500000.00],
    'BedsTotal': [4, 4],
    'MLSAreaMinor': ['Greenways At Sand Creek', 'Keene Ranch'],
    'StreetNumber': [3819, 3231],
    'StreetName': ['Ivy Hill', 'Castle Butte'],
    'PostalCode': [80922, 80109],
    'TaxAmount': [200.00, 4967.00],
})

@app.route('/')
def index():
    price = request.args.get('income', 12000.00, type=float)

    items = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    items = [item for item in items if item['ListPrice'] <= price]

    return render_template('index.html', items=items, income=price)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">
      <form>
        <div>
          <label for="income">Income</label>
          <input type="NUMBER" step="0.01" name="income" id="income" value="{{ '{:.2f}'.format(income) }}" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <div>
      {% if items -%}
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>StreetName</th>
            <th>StreetNumber</th>
            <th>PostalCode</th>
            <th>MLSNumber</th>
            <th>MLSAreaMinor</th>
            <th>ListPrice</th>
            <th>TaxAmount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for item in items %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{item['StreetName']}}</td>
            <td>{{item['StreetNumber']}}</td>
            <td>{{item['PostalCode']}}</td>
            <td>{{item['MLSNumber']}}</td>
            <td>{{item['MLSAreaMinor']}}</td>
            <td>{{item['ListPrice'] | format_currency}}</td>
            <td>{{item['TaxAmount'] | format_currency}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {% else -%}
      <span>No items found.</span>
      {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @robthompson I hope I was able to help you implement your project. Leave me a comment if I've misunderstood you.